# eliminate values that are next to each other in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I use the listagg function in  SQL Oracle to eliminate values that are next to each other? Data can be repeated as long as it is not next to each other.

Example:

```
SELECT RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,colname,',').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY colname).GetClobVal(),',')
  FROM tablename;
```

But I have value:

> apple, apple, apple, apple, apple, apple, apple, apple, apple, apple, apple, apple, pear, apple, orange, orange, orange, orange, orange, grape, grape, apple, grape

How to arrange sql to get such values (repeating but not next to each other).
Excpect:

> apple, pear, apple, orange, grape, apple, grape

Any idea?

Comment: i would write a function for that, or stored procedure with refcursor. Maybe its possible with sql, maybe. Most likely you will need plsql.

Comment: You give example code (using `xmlagg`) - but that is a poor example. In the code you posted, the ordering is by "colname", and the tokens you are aggregating are also "colname" - so that particular code will never produce the kind of output you say **you** are getting (where the same token may appear in the comma-separated list in a *non*-consecutive way). You can't get `apple, banana, apple` if the aggregate is ordered by the tokens themselves; you would get `apple, apple, banana`. Rather, to get the output you show, you would have to order by a **different** column - see MT0's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT LISTAGG(colname, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ROWNUM)
         AS items
FROM   (
  SELECT colname,
         LAG(colname) OVER (ORDER BY ROWNUM) AS prev_colname,
         ROWNUM AS rn
  FROM   tablename
)
WHERE rn = 1
OR    prev_colname <> colname
```

Or, from Oracle 12:

```sql
SELECT LISTAGG(colname, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ROWNUM)
         AS items
FROM   (
  SELECT colname,
         ROWNUM AS rn
  FROM   tablename
)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY rn
  MEASURES
    FIRST(colname) AS colname
  PATTERN (same+)
  DEFINE same AS FIRST(colname) = colname
);
```

*(Note: `ROWNUM` should be replaced by a column that will identify a deterministic ordering in the rows such as a timestamp or an id column; however, such a column is not present in your sample data so it cannot be used. `ROWNUM` will just number the rows in the order that the SQL engine processes them and that processing order may be non-deterministic.)*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tablename (colname) AS
SELECT 'apple'  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 8 UNION ALL
SELECT 'pear'   FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'apple'  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'orange' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5 UNION ALL
SELECT 'grape'  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'apple'  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'grape'  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1;
```

Both output:

> | ITEMS |
> | --- |
> | apple,pear,apple,orange,grape,apple,grape |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=28c921b74fa40e05220d116f2ac85191)*

Comment: What if I have a group with an Id? e.g. will 
1 | apple, apple, apple, apple, apple, apple, apple, apple, apple, apple, apple, apple, pear, apple, orange, orange, orange, orange, orange, grape, grape, apple, grape
2 | ....
3 | same
4 | same
5 | ..... etc.

how to group it by id and eliminate as before in your example?

Comment: @DominikN Add a `PARTITION BY` clause to the `LAG` (or `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`) and then a `GROUP BY` clause. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=8a6d5e520f68a5070e735097d784b342)